# Video to GIF online/offline solution

Tags: video, gif

Is there any free software or a website to convert video to GIF without having watermark of the product in the GIF?

Answer (score 0):

- https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif does it online, it's free and without watermarks, but has 100MB file size limit.
- [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is a great offline, command line tool with many options
  and can be easily used for batch conversions.
- [instagiffer](https://instagiffer.com/) is a pretty good offline, GUI tool.